# How to send a limited amount of inserts at a time. C# System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, commit, system.data.sqlite

I have to read a CSV file (that's not the problem) and do 10 inserts at a time. I do not know how many lines the CSV file will have. I tryed make a Loop and every MOD 10 sends a commit, but after two or three times the program gives error. I have no ideia how to solve this problem.

Edit:

Sorry, Im using my mobile, bit my code is:

```cs
using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("conn-string"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listCode.Count; i++)
        {
            string sql = $"insert into table1 (code) values ({listCode[i]})";

            using (var command = new SqliteCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if ( i % 10 == 9)
                {
                    transaction.Commit();
                 }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the specifics of the error message and the code that causes the error. For other tips see [ask].

Comment: Why do you think you need to do 10 at a time?

Comment: Add code examples

Comment: Its a homework, thats why I need 10 by 10. I'll get my code just tomorrow, I forgot in my workstation. :(

Comment: Without your code, and without your error, we can't help you. If I show up at a car mechanic's shop and say "I experienced a problem while driving my car. I'm not going to tell you what the problem was, and I don't have my car with me" then do you think they're going to be able to help? Why do you think software development is any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that this question is now obsolete, since the homework is probably already past.

However, it is obvious from the code that the first time the `transaction.Commit();` is called, the transaction will be completed.  BUT there is no new transaction started in the loop, so the next time that `transaction.Commit();` is called an error will occur because there will be no active transaction anymore!

Also, you have no code after the loop to handle any residual rows that were not an even divisible of 10.  Even if the original loop code had worked, it could have left uncommitted rows that would not have been properly committed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to process `n` number of items in an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use a combination of the `IEnumerable` extension methods, [`Skip`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiLpa3oyenhAhWOqp4KHVICBUMQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.linq.enumerable.skip&usg=AOvVaw0jKM02R55dq6xEeBjh4LXX) and [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8), where you skip `iteration * n` items and then take `n` items from the list in a loop.

Note that if we increment our loop variable by `n` on each iteration, then that becomes the value that we pass to `Skip`. Also, if there are less than `n` items remaining, `Take(n)` will return all of the remaining items.

For example:

```
// items would be the list of results from reading your csv file. Pseudocode:
List<SomeType> items = GetCSVItems(csvFilePath);

// Set this to the number of items we want to process in each batch
int batchCount = 10;

// To process a batch of 'batchCount' number of items, we first Skip(iteration * batchCount) 
// items in our list, and then we Take(batchCount) items from the list for our next batch
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i += batchCount)
{
    List<SomeType> itemBatch = items.Skip(i).Take(batchCount).ToList();

    // Process itemBatch here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the extension method [`Batch`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.1/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Batch__1.htm) of the library [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ): *Batches the source sequence into sized buckets.*

If you don't want to mess with external libraries you could use the method below, which is a lightweight version of `Batch`.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> BatchForward<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (size <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));
    var counter = 0;
    var batchVersion = 0;
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            counter++;
            batchVersion++;
            if ((counter - 1) % size == 0)
                yield return GetInnerEnumerable(enumerator, batchVersion);
        }
        batchVersion++;
    }
    IEnumerable<TSource> GetInnerEnumerable(IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator, int version)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (version != batchVersion)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration out of order.");
            yield return enumerator.Current;
            if (counter % size == 0) break;
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) break;
            counter++;
        };
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
foreach (var batch in Enumerable.Range(1, 22).BatchForward(5))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{String.Join(", ", batch)}");
}
```

Output:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>   6, 7, 8, 9, 10
>   11, 12, 13, 14, 15
>   16, 17, 18, 19, 20
>   21, 22